# AVAudioRecorder show Statusbar in iOS7

Tags: ios, avaudiorecorder, uistatusbar

I have a boolean with an option to show/hide the status bar in an app

```
- (BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden
{
    return ![[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"showStatus"];

}
- (UIStatusBarStyle)preferredStatusBarStyle
{
    return UIStatusBarStyleLightContent;
}
```

it works great but when i start a new audio recording the status appears all the time..how to start a record and hide the statusbar ?

Answer (score 1):

Im making an app like talk box,
when press the button and start the AVAudioRecorder 
on ios7 is shows a red 40 px height status bar, and disappeared in 1 second.
it makes my app ui bad.
did you find the way to avoid the bar?